# Error: Too many positional arguments: 0 allowed, but 2 found

Tags: flutter, agora.io

Error: Too many positional arguments: 0 allowed, but 2 found.
Try removing the extra positional arguments. configuration.dimensions = VideoDimensions(1920, 1080);

This error happen when I use Agora video call in Flutter.

Answer (score 2):

Error says it doesnt have any positional arguments, instead it has named arguments

which means you need to pass like this

`VideoDimensions(width: 1920, height: 1080),`

Position arguments can be created as

`void functionName(int a, intb);` => `functionName(3,6)`

Optional arguments but named

`void functionName({int a, intb});` => `functionName(a: 4)`

Named and required

`void functionName({ required int a, requried intb});` => `functionName(a: 3, b: 6)`

Optional but not named

`void functionName([int a, intb]);` => `functionName(3,6)`